# Is this possible to create multiple pipeline triggers for target pipeline in yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I'm creating a set of pipelines for my NuGets and want to set up pipelines dependencies for building/publishing all of the changed NuGets in the hierarchy.

Everything works fine if the descendant pipeline has only one ancestor. But in the case when the NuGet has more than one ancestor it won't work. For example, I have the pipeline with the next resources section

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: entity
      source: Entity-Ci
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - '*'
    - pipeline: configuration
      source: Configuration-CI
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - '*'
    - pipeline: dataAbstractions
      source: DataAccess-Abstractions-CI
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - '*'
```

And this pipeline won't start automatically in any case. If I've left only one "- pipeline" section - it works.

Is this possible to create a trigger that runs pipeline in the case when any of ancestors pipelines has been triggered run?

Thanks.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible to create a trigger that runs pipeline in the case
>   when any of ancestors pipelines has been triggered run?

The answer is yes, I tested with multiple pipeline resources and it can work well .

[image]

[image]
[image]

You can try to configure [build completion triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in the UI, choose **Triggers** from the settings menu to see if this works.

[image]

[image]